# How to allow ServiceAccount list namespaces it has access to within a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster with multiple namespaces. Let's call them: `ns1` and `ns2` I also have multiple service accounts, lets call them `sa1` and `sa2`, all in one namespace - `sa-ns`.

Both users can access all resources within both namespaces, however they cannot list namespaces they are part of. `kubectl get ns --as=sa1` returns:

`Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "sa1" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope`

It works only if I manually specify which namespace I want to list:

`kubectl get ns ns1 --as=sa1`

```
NAME           STATUS   AGE
ns1   Active   6d6h
```

I need both users `sa1` and `sa2` be able to list all namespaces within cluster they have access to. In this case `ns1` and `ns2`.

This behavior also probably wont allow me to list namespaces and it's resources in Lens dashboards. From the the namespace list I can list only the namespace `sa-ns` the users `sa1` & `sa2` are part of. Dashboards are however empty as you can seen on the image bellow.

[image]

I tried to add namespace the user has in fact access to via `ACCESSIBLE NAMESPACES` feature in Lens, but it doesn't work either.

[image]

I still don't see anything, only blank dashboards.

[image]

ServiceAccount:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa1
  namespace: sa-ns
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa2
  namespace: sa-ns
```

Role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: admin-role
  namespace: ns1
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "*"
  resources: 
  - "*"
  verbs:
  - "*"
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: admin-role
  namespace: ns2
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "*"
  resources: 
  - "*"
  verbs:
  - "*"
```

RoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-role-binding
  namespace: ns1
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: admin-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa1
  namespace: sa-ns
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-role-binding
  namespace: ns2
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: admin-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa2
  namespace: sa-ns
```

I tried to use `ClusterRole`instead of `Role` but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here is that you don't have access to Namespace resources which are cluster scoped and therefore not included in the Role/Rolebinding combination that you've got. Somewhat unintuitively combining a ClusterRole with a Rolebinding only grants rights to a single namespace as well, which is why that wouldn't work.

Probably the best way to solve this would be to create a ClusterRole that provides GET and LIST rights to Namespace resources and then create a ClusterRoleBinding for each of the service accounts to that ClusterRole.